# C# Controlling dll access

Tags: c#, dll

I have a program that utilises a plugin architecture.  When the inital form loads, it scans the current directory, queries each dll and obtain some basic data which is displayed to the user.

Whilst using the program, the software will often need to ask the dll's to perform some work.

My question is, when the program initially checks the dll files, should I keep a reference to each dll object for future use, or should I query the dll files each time and create the object as and when needed?

if it's the first one, what is the best way to keep a list of an undetermined number of objects that derive from a common interface and then know which one to refer back to when needed?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say save if needed and create when needed :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the first one you could just create a

`List<IYourCommonInterface> pluginDlls`

and then just

`pluginDlls.Add(dllReference);`

**Edit**

Alternate method using a Dictionary, note that this will require you having some kind of ID for the dictionary that you can make use of to id the dlls.

`Dictionary<SomeIDField, IYourCommonInterface> pluginDlls`

`pluginDlls.Add(dllRefrence);`

Comment: (1+) Maybe a dictionary<string,IYourCommonInterface>... that way you've got an easy means of identifying/accessing each resource

Answer (score 1):

Most apps do the check on load.

I wouldn't store the list of interfaces.  If you do store them then you run into the possibility that the assemblies either disappear or are updated in some way.  At which point you need to "refresh" them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've loaded the assembly and gotten an instance of System.Reflection.Assembly for reflection (using Assembly.Load(), Assembly.LoadFrom(), Assembly.LoadFile(), etc.), the assembly is loaded. To quote [MSDN on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> ...it is...possible to load specific assemblies into the current application domain
>   at runtime...**There is no way to unload an individual assembly without unloading
>   all of the application domains that contain it.** Even if the assembly goes out of
>   scope, **the actual assembly file will remain loaded until all application domains
>   that contain it are unloaded.** *[emphasis mine]*

So if you want to unload the DLLs until such time as you actually need them, you're going to have to create a new app domain and then unload that. Its easier to just load them and have done with it. You can keep the assemply reference around if you like, but if you call Assembly.Load() again, it won't actually load the assembly: it'll just get a reference to the previously loaded assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you've gone through the trouble of finding and loading the DLLs, normally you'll want to keep them around. This would depend mostly on how many resources the DLLs use and how your app is using the DLLs.

I'm assuming you're using LoadAssembly here. You can just store references to the assemblies you've loaded using some kind of map. Or even a list that you iterate through.

Perhaps if you give some more details we can help you better.

Comment: Effectively, upon program load, the program queries the dll and displays their identifier/name to the user.  The user can then select one and some external data, and the dll then knows what to do with that data.

Comment: So at some point you have to create an instance of a class that is defined in the DLL, but that implements a common plugin interface you've defined in your main app. There are various ways to do this. Upon loading, for example, the DLL could register itself with some kind of registry in the main app. Or you could look up the class name of the specific instance using reflection, deriving the name from the DLL. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c3da5226-fc87-4fff-be60-4cc5af4d6c07 for some examples.

Comment: I think a more idiomatic solution to identify the plugin classes would be a combination of an interface and an attribute. After loading the assembly, iterate over all the types in it and select those that have your attribute on them and that also directly or indirectly implement your interface. As an example, see the way cmdlets are identified by PowerShell.